# parsing xml from a URL list

Tags: r, xml, url, for-loop

I have a list of URLs that direct to different xml files and I want to extract some info from them using R and the xml package.

I am trying to do this with a `for` loop.
I have this code but it gives me only the last xml (`numtotal`), how can I read all of them?

```
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = numtotal, by = 1)){
  urli <- xmlParse(urls[[i]], useInternalNodes = TRUE)
  top_numberi <- xmlRoot(urli)
  GS = data.frame(GS = xpathSApply(top_numberi,"//a//b",xmlValue))
}
```

where:

- `urls` is a list of 7 or more URLs
- `numtotal` is the length of another list (numeric value)

Comment: Use `lapply` instead so everything is in a list.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote with that rationale. The error is obvious and was easily answered with the small amount of code. Almost certainly was a duplicate because failing to index assignments inside for loops is such a common error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iteration of your `for` loop is overwriting your `GS` data frame. Instead of using a data frame, create a list outside the loop

```
l = list()
```

Then fill in the elements inside the loop

```
l[i] = xpathSApply(top_numberi,"//a//b",xmlValue)
```

---

As an aside, this is a very basic question. You should read some standard R textbooks before proceeding much further.